# Special characters in websites

Tags: javascript, html, string

In HTML and JavaScript sometimes you have to replace certain characters with special escaped versions.

For instance, JavaScript `&` would be changed to HTML `&amp;`, and JavaScript `<` would be changed to HTML `&lt;`.

What is this process called, and are there native or non-native JavaScript routines that can perform this task bi-directionally?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: It's called escaping or encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This special characters called **Entity** , and its text  that begins with an ampersand (&) and ends with a semicolon (;), Some special characters are reserved for use in HTML, meaning that your browser will parse them as HTML code. For example, if you use the less-than (<) sign, the browser interprets any text that follows as a tag. so if you want to display that special charterer you need to write its **entity** , and its the **browser job**  to **unescape** or **mapping**
the chars to their corresponding values

so its escape and unescape or mapping 
and its something that the browser did himself when you write the entity 
you can see a list of html entities 
[Character entity reference](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Comment: I have to pass strings from a database to a PHP page. Is there a routine that can do the escaping just by running it?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) and [`unescape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) js functions alternatively.

Comment: Both methods are deprecated

Comment: You can use `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` js function. But these functions will not work with  - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )  characters. [Brief info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: @Gru: I read the article you linked to but I think it talks about something else.